# Prevent valign='middle' from being overridden by stylesheet declaration?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td valign='middle'><a href='#'>Link</a></td><td><img src='img.png'></td></tr>
</table>
```

And a stylesheet like this:

```
a {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

td a {
  vertical-align: default;
}
```

I'm trying to get my link to be veritcally aligned, but because of my initial `vertical-align: baseline` declaration (which I cannot change) the `valign` attribute is ignored.  I'd like to fix this in the stylesheet under the `td a` selector.  How can I fix this?

(I am testing this in Chrome 12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `valign="middle"` and then in the stylesheet do:

```
td a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Since you were asking how to "erase" the declaration. You can't erase it but you can override it:

```
a {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

would replace the previous declaration in your stylesheet.

Comment: This works (thanks!) --and I'll accept your answer as soon as I can--but is there anyway in a stylesheet to 'erase' a previously declared property?  Without any vertical-align specifications it works just fine with the `valign="middle"` attribute value.  Otherwise I have seemingly-irreparable problems.

Comment: You can't erase a property, just set it something else…

Comment: IMHO its better to use CSS only and get away from attributes in the HTML. I'll edit my answer to show how you can override the default on the a tag

Answer (score 0):

Odd issue you’re having, as [according to Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align), the default value for `vertical-align` *is* `baseline`, so your rule `a { vertical-align: baseline }` shouldn’t have any effect. Is there any other CSS applied to the link?

In modern browsers (like Chrome 12), you could try:

```
td[valign="middle"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any other styles applied, but I'll check it out and get back to you.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @beanland: see e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/JD9wg/1/ — isn’t this rendering how you expect?